# event tracking in google analytics using gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently started learning Google Analytics(GA). I have single page application in Angular. There is a login button in the application. I wanted to track how many users are logged in using GA. So what i did is i created a property in GA and got the tracking id . Then i added the following script just after the in index page.

Now i added the ga() if the login is successful . But unfortunately when i successfully login , i can't find any data in Event Category and Event Action listed in REAL-TIME->Events->bottom most table . I am not able to figure out why?

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

```js
$http({enter code here
          method: 'POST',
          'async': true,
          'cache': false,
          'global': false,
          url: //the  correct url,
          isStaySignIn: isStaySignIn,
          isIdamOn: true,
        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {
          $rootScope.Loading = "Loading";
          deferred.resolve({
            data: data,
            headers: headers
          });
          
          ga('send', {
            hitType: 'event',
            eventCategory: 'MODE',
            eventAction: 'IDAM',
            eventLabel: 'Login using Jio ID'
          });
        })
```

Comment: You're using gtag.js as the method of implementation for GA, you shouldn't be using ga() methods as that's really for the analytics.js method.

Answer (score 12):

You should be using gtag.js to send GA events, since that's your method of implementation of GA, not ga() as that's for analytics.js.

The pattern to send an event is:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

Updated snippet:

```js
$http({enter code here
          method: 'POST',
          'async': true,
          'cache': false,
          'global': false,
          url: //the  correct url,
          isStaySignIn: isStaySignIn,
          isIdamOn: true,
        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {
          $rootScope.Loading = "Loading";
          deferred.resolve({
            data: data,
            headers: headers
          });
          
          //send login event using gtag.js
          gtag('event', 'IDAM', {
            'event_category': 'MODE',
            'event_label':'Login using Jio ID',
          });

        })
```

Comment: could I use something like this for a specific case (tha is not tracked automatic) in combination with default Script automatic gtag on _app.js?