# How do I set up my google analytics events manualy

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Analytics Tracking code. I have set up a whatsapp and email share and I would like to track when these are clicked.
I have inserted my Google Analytic Tracking Code in my header and it works. For my events I have set this up.

`<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=&text=<?php the_permalink(); ?>" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'Share', 'Whatsapp');" target="_blank"></a>`

I have checked on Google analytics Real Time and I can see that the page view is firing but when I click on the whatsapp share it is not showing up in the events. Am I missing something that should be added which is preventing the event from firing?

Comment: Ho do you implement Google Analytics pageview? With ga(), gtag.js or Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Thank you very much, you put me on the right track. I was using gtag.js to implement the pageview. I amended my code in the link and it is working now.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. However, in this case, you can already find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993722/event-tracking-in-google-analytics-using-gtag-js